# d-link camera D933L in xubuntu?

Tags: xubuntu

How can i install a d-link camera D-933-L in Xubuntu?
I tried to install the software from D-link, but it does not work. I searched in ternet but i did not succeed to find the solution.

Answer (score 1):

D-Link does not seem to support Linux operating systems. However, you can still access the camera using its web interface. Just access your routers settings and find its local IP address. Your router's settings page can be accesses by typing '192.168.1.1' or '192.168.0.1' into your browser.

After logging into your router with the correct username and password, there should be a page detailing all of the devices on your network. Find your camera's IP address and type it into your browser.

You should now be at your camera's web interface.

**Note: Some cameras require the use of adobe flash. You can find a guide for installing flash here:** https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/net-install-flash.html